# Function to scale float values to (0-100) in C

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, scale

I am trying to convert a float variable into an integer of value between 0 and 100. The float is always positive. the corresponding integer value should reflect the size of the float value compared to the maximum value for a 32-bit float, e.g. 0.0 converts to 0 and 3.402823466 E + 38 converts to a 100, and anything else goes in between.

Here is what I have so far but I keep getting -1 as the output for any non-zero input.

```
int convFloat(float x){
    int y;
    y = (int) (x/3.4e38) * 100;
    return y;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to divide by `3.4e36`. Then no need to multiply by 100 and no risk of borking the intermediate results.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
y = (int) (x/3.4e38) * 100;
//  ^--------------^
//  cast (x/3.4e38)to int
```

Should be:

```
y = (int) ((x/3.4e38) * 100);
//  ^----------------------^
//  cast ((x/3.4e38) * 100)to int
```

Comment: OK, yes, but why does OP get -1 and not 0?

Comment: This is no real help. Doing a quick bit of testing, it produces 0 for essentially all inputs, which really no improvement.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - the scaling is for very large numbers, so you'll get 0 for many numbers indeed , but in the range of E36-E38, the scaling will result in other numbers.

Comment: Is casting to an int the correct operation?  Can you just cast a float to an int like that in C?

Comment: @BinyaminSharet: Ah, I hadn't considered that, but you're right. The largest number I tested with was e+34, which seemed like it was large enough it should have been non-zero, but thinking again that's not the case.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - I understood that only after getting many 0 myself :)

Comment: It just seems odd with the scientific notation.  The operation 'seems' non-linear because it only generates non-zero for a small range of the exponent, but of course it's not. Cosmologists and subatomic physicists lose track of 'normal' numbers - if you send an astronomer to the grocers for six oranges he/she will come back with a million.

Comment: @myMDB: No. The problem is that it sort of needs to be non-linear to keep from producing this seemingly-strange result. The problem is probably easiest to think of in terms of exponents. Given a maximum exponent of 38, it follows that all exponents smaller than 36 should give a value of 0 (1e+38/100 = 1e+36). Logarithmic scaling would produce a result closer to what most would probably expect (e.g., 1e+10 being between one fourth and one third the way to the maximum).

Comment: Could you please write the logarithmic scaling function? I'm not sure I see your point.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: we don't know how/where the scaled value is used, so whether scaling should be linear or not is moot unless clarified.

Answer (score 0):

```
((union { float f; uint32_t u; }){ val }.u>>23&255)*100/255
```